# Docker Image: Create Internally available environment variables

Tags: docker, dockerfile

On my image I want to set some environment variables eg: `MY_VAR` where it will have a static value eg: `MY_VAR=12` but I do ***NOT*** want to be able to set it via docker's `-e` param or via docker-compose.yml's `environment` section.

Furthermore I do not want to be as build argument when i do either `docker build` or `docker-compose build`

How can I do that?

Comment: Then where *do* you want it to come from?

Comment: I just want to set internally and only the software and scripts running inside docker container to be able to modify it.

Comment: Did you look at `ENV` directive available in the Dockerfile? You can define static environment variables there

Comment: As far as I'm aware you cannot do that; why do you want to? What's the actual problem you think this would solve?

Comment: But via `ENV` directive you can change its values via `-e` param when running the image into contaiuner where I DO NOT want this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that from an entrypoint script.

In your Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Example entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export VAR=foobar
exec /usr/bin/python "$@"
```

To be more flexible and allow setting it with the `-e` option:

```
export VAR=${VAR:-"foobar"}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for your question is to include an `env_file` on your docker-compose build

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:alpine
    volumes:
      - backup-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./env/.dev
```

Then in your env_file:

```
POSTGRES_USER=my_user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password
POSTGRES_DB=my_db
```